# on Mac OSX, from inside terminal, how to input password that contains a special character?

Tags: macos, passwords, terminal, control-characters

I was making a script to change the password of login to one of my VPS machine, and it's something like the following, and unfortunatelly the ^M character (not the combination of '^' and 'M') was added mistakenly into the script. And now I couldn't login to the machine anymore. I found out the character when editing the script using vi. Now I am wondering what should I input when being asked for the password. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "passwd <<EOF
testpass^M
testpass^M
EOF";
```

Comment: Command+V comes up as ^M for me.

Comment: `^M` is the control character for newline. What should work is hitting `ctrl-v` then return (then return again to actually send the password).

Comment: On my machine, Command+V is paste. Tried with ctrl-v, not work neither. :(